# Initial state for deeply nested objects in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, stateful

In one of my containers (component + redux access) I try to do this:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {    
  return {
    url: state.projects.byId[state.selection.projectId].url
  };
}
```

My initial state in the reducer is an empty object `{}`. When my component gets up and running, it requests some data from an API to fill in the state. However, since initially my initial state is empty, I'll get an error that `url` is not defined. Fair enough.

One solution I came up with (and what I would normally do) is to create an initial state that has some dummy data similar to the one I will eventually get back from the API.

However, this is the first bigger project I am working on and my state is becoming quite nested and pretty deep, so I'm wondering if there is something better available? I am also not sure if the solution I came up with is best practice.

Comment: How do you use `url` in your component? You can render it conditionally instead of using dummy data.

Comment: You can use a library like `lodash.get`  or something similar (https://gist.github.com/harish2704/d0ee530e6ee75bad6fd30c98e5ad9dab#gistcomment-2339206) to access stuff without breaking in case things are not available.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to design your state space and UI so that empty arrays `[]` and empty objects `{}` have a meaningful "representation" as an UI. For example, an empty list may trigger a search result page to show `No results`.

A second trick of the trade is to indicate the loading state in a lazy-loading fashion. For example, you may partially render the UI without the actual data and show placeholder elements where data is still missing. There are many techniques: study your favorite sites and see how they solve this problem.

Finally, ask yourself this. Is the URL something that is shown to the user? Remember, the UI is supposed to be JSX + `props` + `state`. If the url is used to request more data, it does not belong to the UI, but the middleware where impure code lives in the React/Redux architecture.